# Updating a model with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, paperclip

The workflow of my app is as following, a with an angularjs frontend app, a user creates an article, if successful, has to submit an image.

I ran `rails generate paperclip article verification_token` that created the following migration:

```
class AddAttachmentVerificationTokenToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :articles do |t|
      t.attachment :verification_token
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :articles, :verification_token
  end
end
```

and in my controller I created a new action, `send_verification_token`

```
def send_verification_token
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update_attribute(:verification_token, params[:file])
    render json: @article.id, status: 201
  else
    render json: @article.errors, status: 422
  end
end
```

But I get and error, that `verification_token` is not a method. Paperclip generated `verification_token_file_name`, `verification_token_content_type`, `verification_token_file_size`, `verification_token_updated_at`, so I'm not sure which attribute should I instead update.

How do I update the model to upload an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to define the attachment (`has_attached_file`) in your model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :verification_token

  validates_attachment_content_type :verification_token, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

That method has a lot of options, check the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods